# What if I change files in design/adminhtml/default/default/template/../../ directory

Tags: magento-1.9, adminhtml, magento-core

I need to change order page of magento's admin panel location of this page is-

**design/adminhtml/default/default/template/sales/order/view/tab/info.phtml**

Somewhere I heard if you want to make changes in core file then you need to rewrite core file. Is these "default/default" folder files comes under core files of magento?

What if I directly replace my code instead this code? Code is working properly so there is no any issue with it.

Please help me on this

Comment: Yes, that does come under the category of "Core" files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you edit these files, you do edit a core file. When upgrading Magento to a new version or sometimes when patching, this file might be overridden.

What you could do is create a custom extension and set a custom template for that page. That's what I normally do, so I'd try that if I were you.

Another option might be that Inchoo created an extension (see: http://inchoo.net/magento/custom-admin-theme-in-magento/) to use a custom adminhtml theme.